# How to plot shapefiles on Bing Map

Tags: gis, shapefile, bing-maps

How can I use shapefile(.shp) with bing maps without using any third party reference?
I just want to use bing maps api library to perform this action. 
So suggest me how can i achieve this?

I have tried something with bing maps which is described below..
Here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GISFunctions.asmx/GetShapeFileData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var response = data.d;
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    var polygonGeometry = response[i];
                    var vertices = new Array();
                    var numCoordinates = polygonGeometry.length;
                    for (var j = 0; j < numCoordinates; j++) {
                        var CoOrdinates = polygonGeometry[j];
                        var x = CoOrdinates[1];
                        var y = CoOrdinates[0];
                        vertices[j] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(x, y);
                    }
                    var polygoncolor = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100, 100, 0, 100);
                    var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(vertices, { fillColor: polygoncolor, strokeColor: polygoncolor });
                // Add the shape to the map
                    map.entities.push(polygon);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

"GISFunctions.asmx/GetShapeFileData" is my web service method. It fetches data from shapefile. Reads shapefile's records one by one and fetches co-ordinates for each record's polygon.
In above Jquery Ajax function, i have differentiated my data and created array which contains vertices for my polygon and then according to below link, i am trying to map these polygons on Bing Map

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427604.aspx

When i go through static data then i can easily plot one polygon on Bing Map.. But when i try to create these polygons dynamically then my above code doesn't work.
It doesn't plot any polygon on map and also don't give my error..

I am new to GIS functions so kindly suggest me right direction..

Comment: You will need to provide more information about what you're trying to do. Please post what you have so far, the code is very helpful.

Comment: Right now i have loaded a basic bing map using following link :

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427624.aspx   now i have a shapefile(.shp) of New Jersey area. I want to highlight new jersey area on bing map using that shapefile or we can say that whatever GeoSpatial data i have in that shapefile(.shp), I want to create a layer according to that shapefile on Bing map.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a couple blog posts on how to import ShapeFiles into Bing Maps. Try taking a look at these:

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/09/06/esri-shapefiles-and-bing-maps.aspx
http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/09/12/esri-shapefiles-and-bing-maps-wpf.aspx
http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/06/18/how-to-load-spatial-data-from-sqlite-in-a-windows-store-app.aspx